# Somebody created a clone of my ERC20 token on the binance.mainnet - is this common?

Tags: erc-20, clone

I am not sure why, but when I googled my project I noted that an ERC20 token with the exact same name as mine was created on the binance mainnet and has even been traded/exchanged on pancake v2

I created my token on the ethereum.mainnet moths before and was still working on the related business and use case, but the clone token now has the name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and common. Token names are just a string variable in smart contracts. So there can be even millions of tokens with same name of your token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite common, unfortunately. Even though the BEP20 token has your project name and symbol, you can still create a BEP20 with same name and symbol. They are not exclusive. For this reason it's important to keep your community aware of fake tokens regularly and make sure they are aware of the correct token contract address they should interact with. You may also reach out to Coingecko / Coinmarketcap (or any other listing service) to report these tokens and ensure they are not associated with your project.